# Scrolling screen capture app for Linux

Tags: linux, screenshot

I am looking for a desktop screen capture app for Linux that will scroll the screen to capture a larger screen area. It is most annoying to try to capture a selected window area where your desired area of capture requires a scrolling of the screen but the capture stops at the bottom without scrolling. Trying to paste together two screen captures is too time consuming.  It should be memory resident and activate upon a key stroke sequence.

I need it to capture not just web pages but also long terminal windows and also windows in other apps.

Additionally, it would be desirable to have a print directly from the app print feature rather than saving as a file and printing from another app.  Annotating and other editing features would be desirable.

Comment: For "terminal windows" I assume you mean the textual output, have a look at the `tee` command` for printing I think (by head) that you could use the `lpr` command.

Comment: There's a bunch of extensions that allow full webpage screen capture. My browser Vivaldi has this feature in built.

Answer (score 2):

I too would like a scrolling screen capture app for Linux.  In the mean time, I have a partial solution if your content can be displayed in a non-maximized window.

In Gnome, the Print Screen (PrtSc) key will bring up a screenshot tool that will let you pick between a selection, the whole screen, or just a window.  With the window option, it's possible to drag your app to the bottom of the screen, then resize the height of the window to the top of your screen.  Continue doing this until you have a huge window that is displaying all the content you want to capture, then just use the screenshot tool to capture the window.

Each app behaves differently as far as moving the content when you resize the window, so you'll probably have to capture intermediate screenshots until you get everything in the window correctly.  Also, at some point, after the window reaches a certain size, the tool will stop showing it in the window list when you push PrtSc.  However, it will still successfully capture the screenshot if you just push the capture button or Enter key.  Good luck, it will take some trial and error, but I've successfully done it with the Gnome Terminal and Telegram Desktop, for example... you'll be quite happy when you finally get that 50,000 pixel tall screenshot you've been wanting.  I was finally able to capture some pokemon!

[image: Tall pokeget screenshot]